# Links not working in Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have a simple iframe that works with loading the url specified, but I can't click links, select text or interact with the site in the iframe in anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="example.com" width="100%" height="100%"><p>your browser does not support iframes</p></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

My browser is Chrome

Comment: Not sure if this could be the case, but are the links in the iframe secure? as in "https://"

Comment: just tested and it t works, which site are you trying to iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Add an opening html tag for starters. Also you will have to add a `<title>` tag in the head in order to validate your html. Make sure you have the full path in your iFrame's src.

If I ever find myself in a situation where HTML isn't acting the way I expect it to, I run it through the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) first and ensure that my HTML is completely valid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <title>some title</title>
   </head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="100%"><p>your browser does not support iframes</p></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My bad for missing that in the question, but I already have an opening html tag in my real code.

Comment: Does it validate in the HTML validator?

Comment: Yeah I just tested and it does

Comment: My code works perfectly. Not sure what's happening on your end without seeing the actual code. Check to ensure that you have the full path in the src attribute.